# Is every sub-lattice of $\mathcal P(X)$ isomorphic to a sub-lattice of $\mathcal P(X')$ containing a singleton set?

Tags: order-theory

Let $X$ be a finite set. $\mathcal{P}(X)$ denotes the set of all subsets of $X$.

Let $\Gamma$ be a sub-lattice of $\mathcal{P}(X)$, i.e. $\Gamma$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ closed under union and intersection. Suppose $\Gamma$ non-empty and $\Gamma$ not made only of the empty set.

Set $$n:=n(\Gamma):=\min\{m\geq1\,|\, \Gamma\text{ contains at least one set of cardinality }m\}$$
and suppose $n\geq2$.
**I would like to find a lattice $\Gamma'$ isomorphic to $\Gamma$, but with $n(\Gamma')=1$.**

With this purpose I thought to define a map $\Phi\!:\Gamma\to\Phi(\Gamma)=:\Gamma'$ doing the following operations:

- from each set $A\in\Gamma$ with cardinality $|A|=n$, choose $n-1$ elements and delete them; (*Notice that all these sets $A$'s are pairwise disjoint, by the minimality of $n$ and since $\Gamma$ is closed under intersection*)
- call $Y$ the set of all deleted elements;
- from each set $B\in\Gamma$ with cardinality $|B|>n$, delete the elements of $Y$.

Clearly in this way one obtains $\Gamma'\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X')$, where $X':=X\smallsetminus Y$. By construction $n(\Gamma')=1$.

It is trivial that $\Phi$ is surjective. It is also easy to check that $\Phi$ is an homomorphism of lattices (i.e. $\Phi(A\cup B)=\Phi(A)\cup\Phi(B)\,$, $\,\Phi(A\cap B)=\Phi(A)\cap\Phi(B)\,$): it suffices to write $\Phi(A)=A\smallsetminus Y$ and apply elementary facts of set theory.

Therefore to conclude it remains only to prove that **$\Phi$ is injective**. I think it is true because I don't manage to build any counter-example. Can you help me to prove it?